# GitHub: How to fork a public repository as a subdirectory in a private repository?

Tags: git, github

My project is currently hosted in a private repository. I'm looking to introduce a dependency to a third party library hosted in a public repository on GitHub. How can I fork the library so that it becomes a subdirectory in my project, but I can still sync from the trunk branch of that library?

Comment: Do you need to modify this public project, or just incorporate it into yours and update it periodically?

Comment: If you need to modify this public project, you should fork instead of using it as submodule.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is called submodule and is described in details at http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 7):

This sequence would get you set up:

```
cd <my-project-dir>
git submodule add <github repository> <my-third-party-dir>   # -b <branch> optionally
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

At this point you've got *my-third-party-dir* populated with a particular commit (a detached head).  Your project will have two changes.

```
git add .gitmodules <my-third-party-dir>
git commit -m 'Added <repository> as a submodule'
```